# Can't boot Ubuntu after installing it alognside windows 10

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader, 20.04

I tried to add the grub loader from windows with Easybcd and also from a live Ubuntu mode but nothing has changed. Here you find the error log and thanks in advance https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XGRShwkKV8/

Comment: Hello, please tell us the contents of the previous post!

Comment: @SambhavSurana just the same i deleted it from stackoverflow to post it here

Comment: Boot-Repair added an Ubuntu UEFI boot entry that you did not have before. Have you updated UEFI? Updated SSD firmware? Made sure drives are set to AHCI in UEFI(but added Windows AHCI drivers first) and made sure Windows fast start up is off (note it will turn it back on with updates).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi & https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/

Comment: I had to reinstall ubuntu after disabling secure boot and fast start-up on windows. thank you very match it was very helpful